# SQL query to fetch the last users who created content orderd by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a oneToMany relationship between User entity and Post entity. Each user can create as muck posts as he want. Tables look like:

```
User(id, name)

Post(id, post_owner_id, content, date) // post_owner_id is the foreign key
```

My goal is to fetch the last users who created posts. I started by:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `post` 
ORDER BY post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and it is giving me correct result. But when I add `GROUP BY post_user_id`, it shrinks the result to only one row per user but with unordered date. What am I missing?

I believe that I need  a JOIN to get the final goal but I need first to find a solution for this first part. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: do you mean the latest 30 posts and the corresponding users?

Comment: @vkp. thank you for your feedback. I mean the latest 30 users who created posts. I need a table of users with the date of their last post.

Comment: post_user_id is not a field in Post. I assume you mean post_owner_id?

Comment: show us a demo at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @JonWilson, yes Jon a lot of work hours can do such bad explaining

Comment: it is not obvious since I never used that site. give me some time please. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I need a table of users with the date of their last post.*

```
SELECT post_owner_id, max(date) as maxdt
FROM  `post`
group by post_owner_id
order by maxdt desc
limit 0,30

select id, maxdt, name
from (
SELECT post_owner_id, max(date) as maxdt
FROM  `post`
group by post_owner_id) t join `User` u on u.id = t.post_owner_id
```

You don't even need a sub query.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, max(p.`date`) as maxdt
FROM  `post` p
JOIN `User` u on u on u.id = p.post_owner_id
group by u.id, u.name
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't write the most accurate comment. In fact, I need `a table of users with all their info+ the date of their last post`. I believe the max aggregated function will do the trick but how to fetch also the name of user. don't joining this with another query is the answer? Thanks again

Comment: see the edited answer. I think that is what you need.

Comment: Yes sir, perfect it is exactly what I did before coming here: `SELECT u.*, t.maxdt 
FROM  fos_user AS u
INNER JOIN (SELECT post_user_id, max(post_date) as maxdt
FROM  post
group by post_user_id
order by maxdt desc) AS t
ON u.id=t.post_user_id
`. Thanks again sir